# Can you include settings for a project in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, default-settings

In VS code version 1.35 is it possible to set the default settings for a project but not override a user's main settings? I'm familiar with setting it for an application:

- Windows in menu File → Preferences → User Settings
- Mac in menu Code → Preferences → Settings or ⌘,

but the project manager would like to make sure the code is structured accordingly and since everyone has their own preferences is it possible in the master branch to include a file with the default settings similar to an individuals':

```
{
  // I want my default to be 4, but JS/JSON to be 2
  "editor.tabSize": 4,
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2
  },
  "[json]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2
  }
}
```

I wasn't able to find this under the tag [visual-studio-code](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code). In VS code is there a way to ship the application settings for a repo?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/), which requires the extension [**Editor Config for VS Code**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig). EditorConfig is quite popular and can be applied to any project.

In your case, you can create a file called `.editorconfig` at the root of your project with these contents:

```
root = true
# The above line prevents the EditorConfig
# extension from finding additional
# .editorconfig files in parent directories.

[*]
indent_size = 4
indent_style = tab

[*.{js,json}]
indent_size = 2
```